# Different headers based on current route using ui-router and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using AngularJS and ui-router. I need to load a different header based on the current state (the user is logged or not).

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="container"></div>
```

Here are some of the states I'm having:

- root - everything is based on it
- root.protected - have some special resolve statements to access
  protected pages when the user is logged
- root.protected.home - a protected page
- root.login - an unprotected login page

How can I define different header (view + controller) based on the state?

There should be one header the user tries to access root.login, and different one accessing root.protected.home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two templates: one for "protected" and one for "login":

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("root", {
            abstract: true,
            template: "<ui-view/>"
        })
        .state("root.protected", {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view="header"></div><div ui-view="container"></div>'
        })
        .state("root.protected.home", {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                header: { templateUrl: "/home-header.html" },
                container: { templateUrl: "/home-container.html" }
            }
        })
        .state("root.login", {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "/login.html",
            controller: "loginController"
        });
```

You can write whole login html code in `login.html`. The better solution is to have a state named "unprotected" and define two `ui-view` for it:

```
        .state("root.unprotected", {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view="header"></div><div ui-view="container"></div>'
        })
        .state("root.unprotected.login", {
            url: "/login",
            views: {
                header: { templateUrl: "/login-header.html", controller: "loginHeaderController" },
                container: { templateUrl: "/login-container.html", controller: "loginContainerController" }
            }
        });
```

And also a more better solution is to not define a `ui-view` for header part of unprotected and have only one `ui-view` for its container. With this approach you don't need to define header for every unprotected view (if you have any). So you just need to write container template.

Comment: Thank you for your response. While I wanted to use the same base template, for both root and root.protected it helped me to solve the issue realizing I have to replace the header view at root.protected state.   
        $stateProvider.state("root.protected", {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header@': {
                    templateUrl: emisConfig.baseDir + "/views/partials/header-protected.html",
                }
            },